# Direct sum of subspaces projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum, projection-matrices

Let $V$ be the space of continuous functions $f: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Define $P_E: V \to V$ and $P_O: V \to V$ by $\forall x \in [-1, 1], \forall f \in [-1, 1],$

\begin{align*}\left(P_E f\right)\left(x\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\left[f\left(x\right)+f\left(-x\right)\right] & & & & (1) \\
\left(P_Of\right)\left(x\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\left[f\left(x\right)-f\left(-x\right)\right]   & & & & (2)
\end{align*}

1. Show that $P_E$ and $P_O$ are linear transformations; then that they are projections; and finally that $P_O = I - P_E$; where $I$ is the identity transformation.
2. How are the nullspaces and the images of $P_E$ and $P_O$ related to each other?
3. Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials with degree less than or equal to n. Compute $P_E(p)$ and $P_O(p)$ for $p \in P_n$. Can you explain why $P_E$ and $P_O$ are called projections onto the even part and the odd part, respectively?

---

I did (1) + (2) and (1) - (2), and got $$f\left(x\right)=\left(P_E f\right)\left(x\right)+\left(P_Of\right)\left(x\right),$$ and $$f\left(-x\right)=\left(P_Ef\right)\left(x\right)-\left(P_Of\right)\left(x\right)$$

Not sure how to go from there.

Comment: How do you define a projection in your course? Is a linear operator a projection if it satisfies $P^2 = P$?

Comment: Your algebra goes wrong. Your third equation is your first one with a sign flipped, not good. The rest I cannot follow either.

Comment: @TheoBendit, we learnt projection matrix before but not yet linear operator as a projection. But I think it makes sense if $P^2 = P$

Comment: Often, when people refer to a projection, they mean an orthogonal projection, which only makes sense in an inner product space. In this case, often they mean $P^2 = P$ and $P$ is self-adjoint. It's hard to answer definitively, unless you have some kind of definition to hand!

Comment: @xsj0101 If you're happy just verifying that $P^2 = P$, it's not too hard to do. You can show $P_E f$ is always even, and $P_O f$ is always odd. Then, you can show that, if $g$ is even, then $P_E g = g$, and if $g$ is odd, then $P_O g = g$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks! I verified that Peg=g and Pog=g. But how does that mean Pe and Po are projection matrix if the question didn't say specify that f is either even or odd?

Comment: @xsj0101 They don't correspond to projection **matrices**, as they are operators on the infinite-dimensional space $V$. They won't have matrices at all. But, if you show $P_E f$ is always even, and $P_E g = g$ whenever $g$ is even, then putting these together gives $P_E^2 f = P_E (P_E f) = P_E f$ for any $f$ (not just even), hence $P_E^2 = P_E$. Similarly for $P_O$, but with odd instead of even.